# How to change the mapper/reduce memory in HDInsight

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I'd like to change some of the properties of my HDInsight cluster within the yarn-site.xml and mapred.site.xml files after I provision my cluster. Properties such as  `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`, `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb`, `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` etc. What happens if I directly change them from those files? Do they disappear when the VM get re-imaged?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are removed when the VM is re-imaged. You should programatically create the cluster and set those values if you want them to persist.

Check out this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/04/15/customizing-hdinsight-cluster-provisioning-via-powershell-and-net-sdk.aspx